# Can you give me a hint finding a sum of this arctangent?

Tags: summation

Well, I am trying to solve find a sum of arctan, but can't find a way.

Can somebody give me a hint?

$\Sigma^\infty_{n=1}tan^{-1}(n+1)-tan^{-1}(n)$

I have tried to integrate it but it seemed way too complicated. I hope there is another way.

The answer is $\frac{\pi}{4}$ by the way.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** Use telescopic formula
$$\sum_m^n f(k+1)-f(k)=f(n+1)-f(m)$$

---

**Details:** With partial sums 
$$s_n=\sum_{k=1}^n \tan^{-1}(k+1)-\tan^{-1}(k)=\tan^{-1}(n+1)-\dfrac{\pi}{4}$$
then
\begin{align}
\sum_{k=1}^\infty \tan^{-1}(k+1)-\tan^{-1}(k)
&= \lim_{n\to\infty}s_n \\
&= \lim_{n\to\infty}\left(\tan^{-1}(n+1)-\dfrac{\pi}{4}\right) \\
&= \dfrac{\pi}{2}-\dfrac{\pi}{4} \\
&= \color{blue}{\dfrac{\pi}{4}}
\end{align}

Comment: thanks alot. It must have taken a long time to solve.

Comment: You are welcome.

Answer (score 0):

Just simply Expand your whole series to get: $$ \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} arctan(n+1) - arc tan(n) $$ $$= arctan (2)-arc tan(1)+ arc tan(3)-arctan(2).  .  .  .  . arc tan (\infty)  $$

Now , notice that every term is getting cancelled with its additive inverse except $arctan(\infty)$ and $-arctan(1) $

Sum them to get your required answer!